# Unsetting elements of a cakephp generated array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array called $all_countries following this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [countries] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [countryName] => Afghanistan
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [countries] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [countryName] => Andorra
                )

        )
)
```

I want to loop through an array called prohibited_countries and unset the entire [countries] element that has a countryName matching.

```
foreach($prohibited_countries as $country){
  //search the $all_countries array for the prohibited country and remove it...

}
```

Basically I've tried using an array_search() but I can't get my head around it, and I'm pretty sure I could simplify this array beforehand using Set::extract or something?

I'd be really grateful if someone could suggest the best way of doing this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all id e teh array in the format:

```
  Array(
    'Andorra' => 2,
    'Afghanistan' => 1
  );
```

Or if you need to have the named keys then i would do:

```
  Array(
    'Andorra' => array('countryName'=> 'Andorra', 'id'=>2),
    'Afghanistan' => array('countryName'=> 'Afghanistan', 'id'=>1)
  );
```

then i would jsut use an `array_diff_keys`:

```
  // assuming the restricted and full list are in the same 
  // array format as outlined above:
  $allowedCountries = array_diff_keys($allCountries, $restrictedCountries);
```

If your restricted countries are just an array of names or ids then you can use `array_flip`, `array_keys`, and/or `array_fill` as necessary to get the values to be the keys for the `array_diff_keys` operation.

You could also use `array_map` to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using array_filter:

```
$all_countries = ...
$prohibited_countries = array('USA', 'England'); // As an example
$new_countries = array_filter($all_countries, create_function('$record', 'global $prohibited_countries; return !in_array($record["countries"]["countryName"], $prohibited_countries);'));
```

$new_countries now contains the filtered array

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (it's probably not the most efficient way, but it should work):

```
for ($i = count($all_countries) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if (in_array($all_countries[$i]['countries']['countryName'], $prohibited_countries) {
        unset($all_countries[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use the Set class included in CakePHP, you could definitely reduce the simplicity of your country array with Set::combine( array(), key, value ).  This will reduce the dimensionality (however, you could do this differently as well.  It looks like your country array is being created by a Cake model; you could use Model::find( 'list' ) if you don't want the multiple-dimension resultant array... but YMMV).

Anyway, to solve your core problem you should use PHP's built-in array_filter(...) function.  Manual page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

> Iterates over each value in the input
> array passing them to the callback
> function. If the  callback  function
> returns true, the current value from
> input  is returned into the result
> array. Array keys are preserved.

Basically, pass it your country array.  Define a callback function that will return true if the argument passed to the callback is not on the list of banned countries.

Note: array_filter will iterate over your array, and is going to be much faster (execution time-wise) than using a for loop, as array_filter is a wrapper to an underlying C function.  Most of the time in PHP, you can find a built-in to massage arrays for what you need; and it's usually a good idea to use them, just because of the speed boost.

HTH,
Travis